# How can I check if a commit has been updated to my Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to use the Actor API but I am waiting on a commit that contains BVH distortion fix. How can I check if that commit has been added? I am not using Gazebo from source. Would there be a way to update my Actor.cc and Actor.hh files from source?

Commit: https://bitbucket.org/mingfeisun/gazebo/commits/4b7200b44d91f9b3679b5a5d59ff336f131524bb?at=default

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20099/how-can-i-check-if-a-commit-has-been-updated-to-my-gazebo?/) by [bhej](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5475/bhej/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can find the instructions to install Gazebo from source [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install). In your case, since you want to use a custom branch, the [advanced tutorial series](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_a&tut=guided_a1) should be useful to help you figure out how to pull the specific branch you want.

You may end up doing something like this:

```
cd <path to osrf/gazebo clone>
hg pull https://bitbucket.org/mingfeisun/gazebo -b default
hg up default
cd build
<usual build instructions>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2